# How do I combine scale elements by discrete color on ggplot heatmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, heatmap, scale-color-manual

```
output$fairness_heatmap <- renderPlot({

    # Check the user's selection
    heatmap_data <- NULL
    groups <- NULL
    values <- NULL
    color <- NULL
    if (input$fairness_metric == "Equal Opportunity Difference") {
      heatmap_data <- rw$`Equal Opportunity Difference`
      groups <- cut(round(heatmap_data, 2), breaks = c(-Inf, -0.11, 0.10, Inf))
      values <- c(unfair_color, fair_color, unfair_color)
      color <- ifelse((round(heatmap_data, 2) <= 0.10000) & (round(heatmap_data, 2) >= -0.10000), "black", "white")
    } else if (input$fairness_metric == "Average Odds Difference") {
      heatmap_data <- rw$`Average Odds Difference`
      groups <- cut(round(heatmap_data, 2), breaks = c(-Inf, -0.11, 0.10, Inf))
      values <- c(unfair_color, fair_color, unfair_color)
      color <- ifelse((round(heatmap_data, 2) <= 0.1000) & (round(heatmap_data, 2) >= -0.1000), "black", "white")
    } else if (input$fairness_metric == "Equalized Odds") {
      heatmap_data <- rw$`Equalized Odds`
      groups <- cut(round(heatmap_data, 2), breaks = c(0.0, 0.1, Inf))
      values <- c(fair_color, unfair_color)
      color <- ifelse(round(heatmap_data, 2) <= 0.10000, "black", "white")
    }

    # Create heatmap
    ggplot(rw,
           aes(x = rw$label_perc,
               y = rw$prot_attr_perc,
               fill = groups)) +
      geom_tile() +
      geom_text(aes(label = round(heatmap_data, 2)),
                color = color,
                size = 4) +
      xlab(label = "Population with Negative Outcome (%)") +
      ylab(label = "Minority Population in Data (%)") +
      ggtitle(paste(input$fairness_metric, "across scenarios (after reweighing)", sep = " ")) +
      scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                         breaks = breaks,
                         labels = labels) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                         breaks = breaks,
                         labels = rev(labels)) +
      scale_fill_manual("Fairness",
                        breaks = levels(groups),
                        labels = c("Unfair", "Fair", "Unfair"),
                        values = values) +
      theme(
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        rect = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank()
      )
  }, bg = "transparent")

}
```

I need to make sure breaks match what I put on the scale so is there a way to set breaks to `[-.1,.1]` and another color for everything else. Here is what the output looks like for average odds difference:

[image]

I want the scale to be by color so that only `Fair` and `Unfair` are shown in the scale. If I can do that without messing with breaks that would be good but I am open to whatever fixes this.

Comment: Hi Matthew. You're very likely to get the help you are looking for if you include some sample data that will allow folks here to test, verify and demonstrate a working solution. Without this, we would have to recreate a data set with a similar structure and the same names as your data. This would be harder than answering your question, and folks are unlikely to do this here, particularly when you could make it very easy for us by editing your question to include the output of `dput(rw)` and `dput(input)`

Answer (score 0):

For this type of thing I usually try to express the category as a logical expression, then use `scale_*_manual` with logical `values`. Maybe there is some utility in using `cut` here that I don't understand, but for this example, you could do...

```r
if (input$fairness_metric == "Equal Opportunity Difference") {
      heatmap_data <- rw$`Equal Opportunity Difference`
      fair <- (abs(round(heatmap_data, 2)) > 0.11)
      color <- ifelse((round(heatmap_data, 2) <= 0.10000) & (round(heatmap_data, 2) >= -0.10000), "black", "white")
}
# else if ...

# Create heatmap
ggplot(rw,
# ...
      + scale_fill_manual("Fairness",
                        breaks = c(TRUE, FALSE),
                        labels = c("Fair", "Unfair"),
                        values = c(fair_color, unfair_color))
# ...
```